# jQuery error "cannot read property 'call' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a Java programmer trying to write a little javaScript. Bear with me.

I would like a function that updates a total when a digit is entered in any one of the input fields in a table. I have the following line in `$(document).ready(function() { ... }`

```
$("#lineCountTable").find('input').each().bind('keyup', function() { 
    updateTotal(this); 
});
```

In Chrome's debug screen, I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'call' of undefined". The line number pointed to is jQuery-1.8.2.js:611.

I figure I have a syntax error in defining the function to be called. The `updateTotal(inputVar)` function is duly defined later in the JS file; in case someone's interested, it is:

```
function updateTotal(inputVar) {
    var row = inputVar.closest('tr');
    var lineCharge = row.find("dlsRowCharge").html().trim();
    var total = 0.0
    var lineCount = inputVar.val();
    if (isNumeric(lineCount)) {
        total = math.abs(lineCount * lineCharge).toFixed(2);
        row.children(".dlsRowTotal").html("$ " + total);
    }
}
```

I know these functions are usually put inline; I would rather define them separately and call them, unless that's impossible.

Comment: Remove the empty `each()` and use `on()` instead of `bind()`

Comment: Function parameter to `$.fn.each()` is mandatory and anyway, just using `.each()` doesn't make sense

Comment: So `on()` operates on each member of the returned array?

Comment: @arcy Ya, like most prototype jQuery method, it internally loops through matched set

Comment: Type casting in this code is giving me a headache - please use `parseFloat` for `lineCharge` and `lineCount` - this way you'll no longer need `isNumeric` - you'll need to compare per `isNaN`. Also `Math` and not `math`

Comment: Also, `this` will be a DOM Element which you can't call `closest()` on - you need to wrap it in a jQuery object. Your `find()` selector also is incorrect, presumably it needs a `.` class prefix

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan On some browsers, [you can](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) but you are right, obviously not what OP was expecting (because then he calls `find()/html()/val()`)

Comment: Chrome allowed closest, but thanks for the tip, I'd've heard about it later from some other browser's user. Can someone tell me what I'm supposed to use instead of `closest()` and `find()` in those places?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few issues here:

- `each()` requires a handler function and is the cause of your error. That said, it's not needed in this instance.
- you should use `on()` over `bind()` since jQuery 1.7.
- `this` will be a DOM Element which you cannot call jQuery's `closest()` method on. Admittedly there is a native `closest()` method, but it's not well supported yet. For the code to work reliably you need to wrap `this` in a jQuery object.
- `find()` requires a valid selector, which `dlsRowCharge` is not. Presumably this should be `.dlsRowCharge`
- `math` should be `Math`

With all that said, try this:

```
$("#lineCountTable").find('input').on('keyup', function() { 
    updateTotal($(this)); 
});

function updateTotal($inputVar) {
    var $row = $inputVar.closest('tr');
    var lineCharge = $row.find("dlsRowCharge").html().trim();
    var lineCount = parseFloat($inputVar.val()) || 0;
    var total = Math.abs(lineCount * lineCharge).toFixed(2);
    $row.children('.dlsRowTotal').html('$ ' + total);
}
```

Comment: What a nice full answer -- wish clicking the upvote button worked more than once. Thanks. I'm afraid I don't know what 'wrap `this` in a jQuery object" means, but will assume it's embodied in your example.

Comment: ah, almost certainly the $() around 'this' in the call. I'll really have to sit down with a jQuery book since the job is otherwise good and I keep being expected to do these things...

Comment: If you get a chance, have a quick scan through the method list of jQuery: http://api.jquery.com. Even if you don't go in to detail, just the names of the methods give you a clue about what can be done.

Comment: To nitpick - the `lineCharge` should be handled the same way as `lineCount`. As such it can be a number, non-number string and empty - so the values it will have will be: float, NaN or 0. Also, the OP's check if the value of `total` is a number should be kept, but per `isNaN` (currently - user puts in the value "a" in input box, total evaluates to "NaN"; ideally it should present some kind of message). It can also be handled if `input` is of `number` type, which is more elegant I guess